# Nesting of a sequence of functions

Tags: functions, function-construction

Suppose I have two functions, `f` and `g`. I would like to produce, in an arbitrary fashion, a new function like, say, `f[g[g[f[g[]]]]]`. If it was just one function, I could use `Nest`. Any way to do this procedure properly?

Comment: Why don't you simply just input f[g[g[f[g[]]]]]? This works great for me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Composition[f, g, g, f, g]
```

might be what you are looking for.

```
Composition[f, g, g, f, g][x]
```

yields `f[g[g[f[g[x]]]]]`.

Comment: Or the short form `f@*g@*g@*f@*g@x`

Answer (score 4):

```
Nest[f@*g, f@g@##, 2] &[]
```

> ```
> f[g[f[g[f[g[]]]]]]
> ```

```
Nest[f@*g, f@g@##, 2] &[x]
```

> ```
> f[g[f[g[f[g[x]]]]]]
> ```

Also

```
flist = {f, g};
Nest[Last[flist = RotateLeft[flist]]@# &, g[], 5]
```

> ```
> f[g[f[g[f[g[]]]]]]
> ```

and

```
(Composition @@ ConstantArray[f@*g, 3])[]
```

> ```
> f[g[f[g[f[g[]]]]]]
> ```